# How to derive Catalan Number equation?

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

I am looking for a way to derive the Catalan Number equation: 
$$ C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n} $$
from:
$$ C_0 = 1,\qquad C_{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n} C_i\, C_{n-i}\,.$$

Comment: You don't derive it this way, you can at most prove that the formula satisfies the recurrence. There are other approaches to deriving the Catalan numbers.

Comment: Have you tried generating functions?

Comment: @Yuval: One can derive it this way, using generating functions.

Answer (score 5):

Let
$$ f(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0} C_n z^n. $$
The recurrence formula gives:
$$ [x^n]\,\frac{f(z)-1}{z}=[x^{n+1}]\,f(z)=C_{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}C_i C_{n-i} = [x^n]\,f(z)^2 $$
hence
$$ f(z)-1 = z\,f(z)^2 $$
leads to:
$$ f(z) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}.$$
Now it is sufficient to use the binomial theorem to get the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1-z}$ in a neighbourhood of zero in terms of the central binomial coefficients, then manipulate such a series to compute the Taylor series of $f(z)$ and state:
$$C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$$
as wanted.